# SQL to add '-' between numbers-alphates-numbers

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I have an interesting scenario to add `- (minus sign)` between numbers, alphabets and numbers.

Example:

> Input: 123AB56; Output: 123-AB-56;
>
> Input: 56XYZ777; Output: 56-XYZ-777;

There is no regular pattern for the source data.

Any inputs on this is appreciated.

Comment: You have to try something then ask for question when you have a problem. `We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers …` See http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Not very easily on any release of Teradata prior to 14. You will need a UDF to do it effectively. With Teradata 14 use their native regular expression support.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a relatively later Oracle, there is `regexp_replace` for these kind of tasks:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(YOURFIELD,
                 '([[:digit:]]+)([[:alpha:]]+)([[:digit:]]+)',
                 '\1-\2-\3') REPLACED_RESULTS
  FROM YOURTABLE;
```